# Sitecore Commerce website fails to start

Tags: sitecore-commerce

After installation of the Sitecore Commerce, I got this message, for some reasons the ASPNET 2.1 core is not working for this website

website : SitecoreIdentityServer , which is also ASPNET core Works

Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/COMMERCEMINIONS_SC9' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\' created process with commandline 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc9\Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.exe ' but failed to listen on the given port '21614'

[image]

Comment: This is really strange port "21614" that Minions want to use in your case. By Default Commerce instances use ports 5000 on wards. Authoring is using 5000, Shops is using 5005, Minions is using 5010 and Ops is using 5015 ports. Authoring, Shops and Ops instances are working as expected? What are their ports? Which user is set to run Minions Application pool? Is it CSFndRuntimeUser?

Comment: What happens if you just start the Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.exe through the command line? (Make sure you are elevated)